# How to update method parameter value using java stream

Tags: java

I'm working on a mission.

Regarding this mission, the reviewer asked me to change the form to stream, how can I solve this?

```java
  public int next(int memberIndex) {
    int result = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < last(); i++){
      memberIndex = current(i).next(memberIndex);
      result = memberIndex;
    }
    return result;
  }
```

The method I thought was as below, but in this case, `memberIndex` was not updated, so I couldn't get the correct result value.

```java
  public int next(int memberIndex) {
    return IntStream.range(0, last())
        .mapToObj((index) -> current(index)
            .next(memberIndex))
        .findFirst()
        .orElseThrow(IllegalArgumentException::new);
  }
```

`current()` and `last()` methods are shown below.

```java
  private Line current(int index) {
    return this.entireLine()
        .get(index);
  }

  public int last() {
    return this.entireLine()
        .size();
  }
```

How can we solve this?

Comment: Maybe don't try to build the same logic but try to achieve the same result. What is that code meant to do?

Comment: @Thomas Logic to check the result by looping the number of members. MemberIndex needs to be updated continuously to compare the next steps, but I'm not sure how to handle it as a stream.

Comment: Are these the only details that were given?   Otherwise, some assumptions may need to be made.

Comment: @WJS Yes, it was just a matter of changing the source, and we got a hint in the answer below, and we're going to use AtomicInteger 
`memberIdx = atomicInteger(memberIndex);
this.entireLine.forEach(line -> memberIdx.set(line.next(memberIdx.get()));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is the `stream` member of the `ArrayList`.

Using `stream` on your `this.entireLine` which I assume is a `List<Line>`, you can loop over all the elements and perform you logic instead of using a traditional `for loop`

```
public int next(int memberIndex) {
    int result = 0;
    this.entireLine.stream().forEach(line -> {
        memberIndex = line.next(memberIndex);
        result = memberIndex;
    });
    return result;
}
```

Is this what you wanted ?

For more on `Streams`, check this [tutorial](https://howtodoinjava.com/java8/java-streams-by-examples/) out.

Comment: I also tried to handle it similarly, but inside Lambda expression, it was impossible to change the variable because only the final value was processed. How can I solve this problem?

To solve this problem, we processed the result with `AtomicInteger` and made it `return result.get()` at the end, and I wonder if it is the right way.

Comment: Yes, using Atomic is one to solve the problem and it is definitely acceptable.

Comment: Well, using AtomicInteger will solve the effective final problem.  Whether it's acceptable is up to the reviewer.